# Extract .msg files having .eml files as attachment in python?

Tags: python, ole, msg

I am using Olefile to analyse a .msg file having .eml files as attachments. I am able to get the final streams that is the contents of the attached .eml files. But I wan to save the attachment as a whole for further processing aby another application.

How to handle the case when stream tag 37010102 is missing from the attachment storage. But there is a storage with a tag 3701000D present in the attachment storage which again contains an attachment of .eml extension.

Can we save the attachment of the .msg file in which stream tag 37010102 is missing but tag 3701000D is present (or having .msg or .eml as attachment).